# iPad Keyboard Rendering - Missing Letters / Keys

Tags: ios, ipad

I have been working on an app for a number of months now and a strange bug has appeared in the last week or two. After extended use of the application (20-30 minutes), many of our custom labels (based on UILabel) cease to render correctly (some will just appear blank). Interestingly, bringing up the keyboard in this situation shows the following:

[image]

I've tried a number of tweaks over the last couple of weeks to various parts of the codebase with no avail and I was hoping that someone here might have stumbled across a similar problem before and/or might have some ideas of where to look for a solution.

We are using lots of CoreGraphics calls within our custom labels to render some pretty complicated annotated strings and have a fair amount of traffic going back and forth to a server in the background on another thread. With regards to memory, we are using ARC and while we're keeping about 5-10Mb of raw data in memory at any one time - I can't imagine that anything else is chewing up loads of memory.

Any advice on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not this exact problem, but similar really weird stuff visible in a window. It was tracked down to messaging UIKit from other than the main thread. We ended up adding lots and lots of "assert([NSThread isMainThread]);" in places that we thought might be drawing on screen, and sure enough, we found the guilty party.

Comment: +1 for highlighting that UI calls need to be on the main thread.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer, I'll investigate today to see if any of our networking or other threaded code might be calling any UIKit methods! Such a strange bug!

Comment: When you find the problem please, do let us know what it was!

Comment: No joy yet unfortunately, I can't actually find any code that's accessing UIKit from another thread (well apart from once or twice in the networking code - but this bug is taking place when the app isn't being connected to our network). I've wrapped up our UI calls in Cthutu's snippet though and it's still occurring, but I'll keep investigating and update with a comment when we have the solution!

Comment: Well, the only other thing I can thing of is to create a new project, put enough code in it to write one custom label, create an array of strings and then in code just cycle writing it with a different string over and over again - and see if you can get it to corrupt itself as you see now. Have a stop button so you can stop the iterations (add after you see you can create them), then pop a keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the additional idea. Have been on holiday, but am back to trying to crack it today. I think we're going to be remove the custom label from the app and leave it with a tester all day (luckily, we have people here testing the content 9-5 anyway, so they can stress test the app for us). Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Curses, I think it turned out it to be a memory issue after all. A UIViewController was registering for messages as a delegate for another class and this link wasn't being released properly. I need to have the testers play with it tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

On the subject of making UI calls on a different thread, I thought I might add this bit of code to demonstrate how a different thread can make UI calls.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Put your UI code here
});
```

This will ensure your code runs on the main thread during run loop processing.